# how to use OWL API in netbeans connect it to proteje and SWRL to read a OWL file?

Tags: netbeans, owl, protege, swrl

I could add OWL API in my netbeans library  now i want to make connection with proteje and be able to read owl file in my local computer.
do u have some source sample code related to it?

thx

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is something like this:

```
    OWLOntologyDocumentSource source = new FileDocumentSource(new File("ontology.owl"));
    OWLOntology o = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager().loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(source);
```

For more examples check out the OWLAPI [wiki](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation)

Comment: hi--  can you make it more clear for me? please.  I downaloded OWL API and I included to my netbeans library . so now I have OWL API . where should is put this code?  is should be in the sertain class?

Comment: You need to put the local path for your file in place of "ontology.owl". Have you checked out the examples linked in my response? https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/blob/version4/contract/src/test/java/org/semanticweb/owlapi/examples/Examples.java should give you plenty of context on how ontology loading works.

Comment: yes I was browsing on that page but too much information it cause confusion .

Comment: dear ignazio can you help me.  .I have ontology and it  has a class . the name of class is good_food and inside this class I have 3 instances . only i I need to know  how to show this instances on my web page . this is critical for me .I m working with netbeans

Comment: I wrote java with netbeans . UI is jsp pages and servelet is bridge between database and UI .I have one OWL file that I created with protege and I need to show instances on one of my classes(Good_food) in that owl file ON my UI .

Comment: THIS IS MY EMAIL   TARABI419@GMAIL.COM... If you send email to me i will send my all files to you if needed

Comment: I  already coded all SQL section and every thing is working good with my static part of project . THE ONLY PART is this OWL . my thesis is depends on to finish this project , please help me to finish it. thx

Comment: i only have one week to finish this owl section

Comment: I've contacted you on researchgate

Comment: HI-THX. I replayed for you